# HTML form select Output hide

Tags: php, html

I have a form where users have dropdowns.. The form have a get method so that the output values is used for processing.. But the problem is i get all the three values which is not able to be used..

```
<form method="get" action="finish.php">
<select name="case" >
<option value="">*Grimsborough Case*</option>
<option value="1"   >001</option>
<option value="2"   >002</option>
<option value="3"   >003</option>
</select>
<select name="case" >
<option value="">*Pacific Bay Case*</option>
<option value="201"  >PB01</option>
<option value="202"  >PB02</option>
<option value="203"  >PB03</option>
</select>
<select name="case" >
<option value="">*World Edition Case*</option>
<option value="301"  >WE01</option>
<option value="302"  >WE02</option>
<option value="303"  >WE03</option>
</select>
```

These are the forms that I have the output while i select is something like this..

```
finish.php?case=&case=&case=302&submit=%3D%3D>+submit+<%3D%3D
```

I will like to get output like this

```
finish.php?case=302&submit=%3D%3D>+submit+<%3D%3D
```

Please help :)

Comment: You need different `name` attributes for the`select` elements.

Comment: Change name attribute of select elements to have only one name per select

Comment: @nicovank I still get the output like this.. finish.php?case1=&case2=&case3=303&submit=%3D%3D>+submit+<%3D%3D

Comment: change the name attribute like `case` into `case_Grimsborough` and so on and Get the case  `$case = $_GET['case_Grimsborough']`

Comment: @NaveenDA cant we use if select function for the problem?

Comment: Should there be only 1 input? like if he use the first select the other 2 are useless? If yes you should just use 1 select and seperate the "categories" via <optgroup> Tag

Comment: @Tiega Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to name your select elements differently

```
<form method="get" action="finish.php">
    <select name="case1" >
        <option value="">*Grimsborough Case*</option>
        <option value="1"   >001</option>
        <option value="2"   >002</option>
        <option value="3"   >003</option>
    </select>
    <select name="case2" >
        <option value="">*Pacific Bay Case*</option>
        <option value="201"  >PB01</option>
        <option value="202"  >PB02</option>
        <option value="203"  >PB03</option>
    </select>
    <select name="case3" >
        <option value="">*World Edition Case*</option>
        <option value="301"  >WE01</option>
        <option value="302"  >WE02</option>
        <option value="303"  >WE03</option>
    </select>
```

And from your php script, you to do this:

```
$case1 = $_GET["case1"];
$case2 = $_GET["case2"];
$case3 = $_GET["case3"];
```

Comment: cant we use if select function for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood it right you want something like that:

```
<select name="case" >
    <optgroup label="Grimsborough Case">
        <option value="1"   >001</option>
        <option value="2"   >002</option>
        <option value="3"   >003</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Pacific Bay Case">
        <option value="201"  >PB01</option>
        <option value="202"  >PB02</option>
        <option value="203"  >PB03</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="World Edition Case">
        <option value="301"  >WE01</option>
        <option value="302"  >WE02</option>
        <option value="303"  >WE03</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```